# Bad quality of package for installing Linux kernel

Tags: package-management, kernel, 16.04

I was trying to install kernel 4.6 on Ubuntu 16.04 but it didn't go well. I followed these instructions:

> How to Install Kernel 4.6 in Ubuntu:
>
> There are .deb packages for this kernel release available in kernel-ppa/mainline:
>
> [Download Kernel 4.6 (.deb)](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v4.6-yakkety/)
>
> Download and install the packages named below one by one according to your OS type (i386 for 32-bit, amd64 for 64-bit):
>
> ```
> linux-headers-4.6.0-xxx_all.deb
> linux-headers-4.6.0-xxx-generic_xxx_i386/amd64.deb
> linux-image-4.6.0-xxx-generic_xxx_i386/amd64.deb
> ```

I installed two of them with Ubuntu Software Center but on the last one I got this error:

> The package is of bad quality
>
> The installation of a package which violates the quality standards isn't allowed. This could cause serious problems on your computer. Please contact the person or organisation who provided this package file and include the details beneath.
>
> Details
>
> Lintian check results for `/home/MYUSERNAME/Desktop/linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic_4.6.0-040600.201605151930_amd64.deb`:
>
> ```
> E: linux-image-4.6.0-040600-generic: binary-with-bad-dynamic-table lib/modules/4.6.0-040600-generic/vdso/vdso64.so
> ```

I found these steps [here on the Ubuntu handbook site](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/install-linux-kernel-4-6-ubuntu-16-04/).

What is the problem?

Comment: Basically it's a bug in the package. Note that those packages are marked "yakkety", so they are supposedly for installation in the current development release (to become 16.10), not in 16.04.

Comment: @fkraiem So do you know how to install the new kernel and uninstall first packages.