# Undo installation of an unstable kernel

Tags: kernel

I am facing a problem with kernel installation. I installed two packages but the last one didn't. So I want to uninstall the first package. In this link I have described what was my problem. [my problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/777615/bad-quality-of-package-for-installing-linux-kernel)

Comment: Why do you post another question?

Comment: @Pilot6 because it is two different question. I asked old question to fix that problem.  It seems it can't be installed so I asked another question to undo changes.

Comment: You can remove the kernel packages.

Comment: @Pilot6 How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To uninstall a package installed with `dpkg`:

```
sudo dpkg -P name-of-package
```

or

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge name-of-package
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

To get the name of the package first:

```
dpkg -l | grep part-of-package-name
```

in your case

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-headers
```

which is what you installed. The actual kernel is the `linux-image` package - the `linux-headers` are minimal configuration kits to automatically build the kernel and its modules, so it is not really important to remove them as they won't do anything to your system by themselves & won't affect which kernel is used.

To find actual installed kernels to remove them, first check what kernel is running with `uname -r` and **do not remove it**. Then run:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
```

If you have removed an installed kernel you should run

```
sudo update-grub
```

afterwards, to remove it from the GRUB menu.

Comment: Not `linux-headers`, but `linux-image`.

Comment: @Pilot6 According to [the question the OP linked to](http://askubuntu.com/questions/777615/bad-quality-of-package-for-installing-linux-kernel) they successfully installed the headers packages, but the image package failed, and they want to remove the 'first 2 packages' So I guess the question title should be edited  since the image is the actual kernel. What to do? Move content from other question here, edit & delete the other question?

Comment: The headers do not affect which kernel is used. So it is not really important to remove them. You can add some explanation about headers vs image and leave it as it is.